# Where can I see the source code of CoreLocation?

Tags: ios, swift, git, open-source, core-location

I heard that Swift is open-source, and I think all the frameworks are open-source. However, I cannot find the source code of CoreLocation on https://github.com/apple. I can see the source code for Foundation: https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation, but I can't find CoreLocation. Is it available?

Comment: *"I think all the frameworks are open-source"* - Hmmm. No.

Comment: CoreLocation is a system framework, it has nothing to do with Swift

Comment: I think the source for swift is open source . not for apple's  frameworks....I mean the compiler and the  rest of the grammar of the language is open source

Comment: so all the system framwork are not open-source, only CoreFoundation is?

Comment: CoreFoundation is also closed source. The only open source iOS components are: http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/ios-90/

Comment: Part of Foundation has been disclosed due the launch of SWIFT as an open source project, but it's just a little part and yet not fully disclosed https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation here the status page https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Docs/Status.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- CoreLocation isn't open source as it is part of apples private frameworks (like UIKit or MapKit).
- Only the Swift standard library was open sourced much like how Objective-C was.

You will be able to get the source for any of the standard swift library: http://swiftdoc.org

You also have access to the source code for the swift compiler.

TL;DR; No - you cannot get source code for CoreLocation